# In the Outlook 2007 To-Do Bar can I hide specific re-occuring appointments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In outlook 2007's To-Do bar (the bar on the right with the Calendar, your task list and upcoming appointments), is there a way to hide a specific series of appointments?

I have daily appointments for scrum meetings, but I'm not interested in seeing the whole list of them.

I have a feeling this isn't possible, but anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can put the scrum meetings on a second calendar?  It seems that only events on My Calendars->Calendar show up on the To-Do Bar.

Comment: Also, for anyone else, you can also set Outlook to overlay multiple calendars so that you can still see your appointments all at once.

Comment: Great suggestion. NOTE: here are the instructions for creating a new calendar in [Outlook 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-additional-calendars-HP010080031.aspx) and  [Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-additional-calendars-HP010355042.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

To hide reoccurring appointments and set up reminders, create a 2nd calendar.  Use it for all those daily reminders like "fill in your timesheet".  In the Home tab click on Open Calender.  It gives an option to create a new calendar.  On this calendar you can create those reminders and reoccurring appointments without having them clutter up your main calender or the To Do List.  They will send out their reminders the same as on the main calender, even though the calendar they are on is hidden from view.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do what you're saying.

Go to To Do Bar options.

Un-check "Show All Day events"

Then just setup your reoccurring event that you don't want displayed in the To Do List as a full day event.

Your reoccurring event is now NOT displayed in the To Do List but is there on your calendar.

The only 'bug' is that actual appointments that are scheduled as a full day will not be displayed.

Comment: I did not find this option in Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 1):

While as far as I know you cannot hide items, you could colour them so they're easier to ignore. To change a recurring appointment open it (make sure you open the series) and click Categorize. You can choose a colour from the list, or choose All Categories to customize your colours.

Comment: I changed mine to a use a category with a light grey colour, which makes them stand out a lot less that then default appointment category of blue.

Answer (score 1):

To hide an appointment, mark it as private.

Then right click on the appointment area and click on 'Options'. Uncheck 'Show details of private items'

Comment: This doesn't quite solve the issue, as the appointments still appear in the To-Do Bar. It only hides the name of the appointment and replaces it with "Private Appointment".

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Nuts! I just re-read your question and realized you were talking about the appointments section, not the tasks section. I don't think there's a way to hide specific appointments in that section. You can hide all of the appointments by right-clicking on "To Do Bar" and unticking "Appointments", but I can't see a way you can filter them.

---

You can set up a filter on the tasks to hide certain messages/tasks:

- Right-click the task area and select "Filter..."
- Click the "Advanced" tab
- In the "Define more criteria" area:

  - Choose a field (if these meetings all have the name/subject of "Scrum", choose "Subject")
  - Change the condition to **"doesn't contain"**
  - In "Value", put the text of the subject you want ignored (for example, "Scrum")
- Click OK

You can set up all kinds of filters on the tasks area - the only other example I could find was at the [How-To Geek for only showing today's tasks](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/make-to-do-bar-in-outlook-2007-show-only-todays-tasks/).

By default, Outlook has 2 filters already in place it uses to only show incomplete tasks:

- Date Completed (does not exist)
- Flag Completed Date (does not exist)